# Get rid of Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

Personally I think it should be scrapped and started again, assuming there is a good reason to start again that is.

It's pretty basic in functionality so it's not hard to replicate the extent of its uselessness in a few simple steps:

1. Go to "Documentation"
2. Click a topic (e.g. "C# Language")
3. Click a tag (e.g. "Keywords")

**Q.** Now, can somebody explain what benefits that screen provides me as a user?

It's just examples of different keywords, in no particular order, and with no useful context regarding keywords in general.

If I want to know about C# Keyword, I would Google "C# Keywords". If I want to know about a specific one, I would Google "C# [insert keyword] keyword".

Same applies for other topics/tags, just take your pick and get ready to learn nothing useful.

**Q.** What is my motivation to ever want to use the "Documentation" feature, what can I stand to gain from its existence?

I think somebody thought they had a good idea, convinced the right people it was a good idea, and then did a really bad job of making it a reality...

I haven't suggested it should go back into Beta; I am saying it should go into the trash.

Comment: yes, the layout sucks. but a user clicking on documentation and then a topic then a keyword isn't the target audience.

Comment: You are describing stackoverflow.com, just a random collection of often poor questions, clumsily organized by [tags].  12 million of them.  Who could have guessed that *that* would ever get successful?

Comment: @KevinB: Can you offer an example where it is a useful feature?

Comment: Of course. it's useful when the official docs for a given topic are awful/hard to navigate/lacks examples. which happens to be relatively common.

Comment: @HansPassant: But I don't search tags. I Google my question (look for SO as a preferred source for answers) then see if it helps me. If not, I find another Google result. My problem is, you can't find anything that would be useful with Documentation. How are you supposed to use it/navigate it to get any benefit from it? The organisation of SO is irrelevant because I can easily find what I need it for.

Comment: It was never meant to be a manual, Google will index it as well.  It already does.

Comment: "I Google my question (look for SO as a preferred source for answers) then see if it helps me" and that's exactly how documentation is intended to be used by the majority of users.

Comment: @KevinB: But won't you still just land on the "tag" page at best? Which still leaves you in the scenario of having to search the 'random' examples for something that might be of use? If you wan't to build a library then stick with the tried and tested method of section > shelf > book > chapter... then you might have something worth using. I guess in reality, it *might* only take that one extra layer of depth to make it into something workable

Comment: well, no, hopefully you'd end up at a relevant example, or at least a relevant topic.

Comment: @KevinB: But you don't get 'an example', you get a page with lots of different examples about a broad topic. That's the problem, the examples on a single page are far too broad. Without being able to navigate to a more granular level then you can't search for anything that is actually useful.

Comment: @musefan http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/845/promise-chaining

Comment: 1. None. It's a horrible example. You are free to fix it though :) 2. You stand to gain useful examples where none exist in the official documentation.

Comment: If this is a feature-request, it's mistagged; if it's a question, it's too broad. If it's a discussion, you need to clarify what you want to see discussed.

Answer (score 4):

I really don't think starting from scratch is a good idea. In general, you don't want to do that unless you're a lone developer with little experience **or** your business or product is tanking. And of course there's always horror stories of Super Duper Programmers who tank a project by starting over from scratch with their awesome idea and are unable to get it off the ground, costing the business millions of dollars. Let's take a look at some previous Programmers.SE discussions:

[Project is nearly done, but procedural spaghetti code. Do I rewrite or just keep trying to ship it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/249892/project-is-nearly-done-but-procedural-spaghetti-code-do-i-rewrite-or-just-keep)

This is not applicable because we do not know the source code and it doesn't concern us anyways, but there's still some good advice here by [Joeri Sebrechts](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/2063/joeri-sebrechts) here:

> Communicate, communicate, communicate. You must be very open and frank about the state of the project and your ideas on how to proceed, even if you're unsure and see multiple paths. This leaves the business owner the choice on what to do. If you keep knowledge to yourself, you deprive them of choices.

The developers are very good at doing this, so no complaints there.

> Resist the temptation of the full rewrite. While you are rewriting, the business has no product. Also, a rewrite rarely turns out as good as you imagined it. Instead choose an architecture and migrate the codebase to it gradually. Even a horrible codebase can be salvaged this way. Read books about refactoring to help you along.

If they yanked the plug on the project there will be *uproar* because all of the progress and input from the users would be lost. Then we'll be in the dark while they work on a new idea that could take months to come to fruition. The negative backlash and the slim chance of the new idea being better would no doubt cause fatigue and anger from the community.

> Learn about automated testing / unit testing. You have to build up confidence in the code, and the way to do that is to cover it with automated tests. This goes hand-in-hand with refactoring. As long as you don't have the tests, test manually and comprehensively (try to break your code, because your users will do so). Log all the bugs you find so you can prioritize and fix them (you won't have time to fix all bugs, no software ships bug-free in the real world).

There is no better testing method than integration testing (real world usage). Meta also counts as a very successful bug tracker. It's not as unwieldly as a bugzilla which is more appropriate for internal use. Sometimes we forget how successful bug tracking on Meta is because it's basically a forum.

> Learn about how to deploy a web application and keep it running. The book Web Operations: Keeping the Data On Time is a good start.

Again, they're really good at doing this. How many times have you counted them taking the entire website offline to do maintenance in the past 6 months? How many of those times were related to new features? We also see developers responding to bug reports and pushing fixes transparently.

[A large part of my code has a major design flaw. Finish it off or fix it now?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/321463)

TL;DR: it's better to finish off your initial version and get a product out *before* you even think about a rewrite. If Documentation was scrapped everytime it had some form of progress, the users would stop wanting to participate in the beta or discussing the issues and it would probably be stuck in Developmental Hell. And this is a given, but the finished product is usually (but not always) going to be substantially different from the Beta. That's the V2.0 that we want to get to, which wouldn't be possible if we scrap V1.0.

**There are significant issues with Documentation, but starting over is only going to make things worse.**

Comment: The canonical one is, so to speak, *[Things You Should Never Do, Part I](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)*.

Comment: "...but starting over is only going to make things worse." To be fair that is not really what the OP's emphasis was on. The question evolved more around "continue or kill it now" than about the virtues of a rewrite. I agree that if SO wants to continue they should work with what is there, but I'm not sure they actually should continue.

Comment: "*TL;DR: it's better to finish off your initial version and get a product out before you even think about a rewrite.*" How is this "better"? Better for who? Because I fail to see how a disorganized series of generally useless bits of code is an improvement over, well, *anything* right now. Why would anyone bother to participate in "V2.0" if V1.0 was complete trash? Not to mention the fact that the mere *existence* of Docs.SO is actively damaging to Q&A, giving people powers that they would *never* have merited otherwise.

Comment: "*Why would anyone bother to participate in "V2.0" if V1.0 was complete trash?*" Allow me to elaborate on that statement. Version 1.0 of Docs.SO has proven to be a complete waste of everyone's time. The design is inherently contradictory. There's no clear vision for what it's supposed to look like or produce. The system actively encourages negative behavior by its participants. And its mere existence harms the rest of the site. If someone created something with so little thought behind it as their v1.0, why would you waste your time on their v2.0?